# How to get method to run after timer ends?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

(V1) I have a countdown object that deals with displaying a countdown on the JFrame by using a timer. Once the countdown goes to 0, I want the timer to stop and the game to start. However, I realized that even when my countdown isn't finished, my `startGame()` method is being run, and I cannot find a solution to make it so that the `startGame()` method only runs after the timer is stopped. So, my question is: is there anyway to make sure the `startGame()` only runs AFTER the countdown hits zero?

(V2) I tried using `countdown.getTimer.isRunning()`in the `init()` method to check whether or not the timer is running (if not then call `startGame()`) but that didn't seem to work. I'm guessing this is because at the time the if block is called, the timer is still running, so that's why `startGame()` isn't called... Is this why?

A little explanation of the code: the `startCountdown()` method tries to display the next image while hiding the last, so I have the catch for the first case where it tries to hide a non-existant image at an index that is out of bounds. Each time the timer ticks, I decrement sec by 1 until it is 0, and then the timer stops.

V1

```
public void init() {
    countdown.startCountdown();
    countdown.getTimer().start();
    startGame();
}

public void startCountdown() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                if (sec == 0) {
                    countdownIcons.get(0).setVisible(false);
                    timer.stop();
                }
                countdownIcons.get(sec - 1).setVisible(true);
                countdownIcons.get(sec).setVisible(false);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                if (sec == 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
            sec--;
            System.out.println(sec);
        }
    });
}
```

V2

```
public void init() {
    countdown.startCountdown();
    countdown.getTimer().start();
    if (!countdown.getTimer().isRunning()) {
        startGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Timer` method runs on a separate thread, different from your main thread.

The way I see it there are two possible solutions:

- call your `startGame()` method inside `startCountdown()`, not inside `init()`;
- the second solution would be to pause your main thread and wait for `startCountdown()` to finish, something like this should work:

```
public void init() {
    countdown.startCountdown();
    countdown.getTimer().start();
    // pause main thread until timer is notified
    synchronized(timer){
        timer.wait()
        startGame();
    }
}

public void startCountdown() {
    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                if (sec == 0) {
                    countdownIcons.get(0).setVisible(false);
                    timer.stop();
                    // notify your current thread that it can resume execution
                    synchronized(timer){
                         timer.notify();
                    }
                }
                countdownIcons.get(sec - 1).setVisible(true);
                countdownIcons.get(sec).setVisible(false);
            // try not to catch this runtime exception and fix what causes IndexOutOfBoundsException 
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                if (sec == 0) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
            sec--;
            System.out.println(sec);
        }
    });
}
```